# How can Pfister's four-square identity be used to solve problems in number theory, such as finding representations of integers as sums of four squares

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, algebraic-number-theory, intuition, representations-by-quadratic-forms

[Pfister's four-square identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_four-square_identity#Pfister%27s_identity) is a theorem in number theory that states that the product of two numbers, each of which is a sum of four squares, is itself a sum of four squares. I'm interested in learning more about how this identity can be used to solve problems in number theory. For instance, are there any specific types of numbers that can be represented as sums of four squares in this way? Are there any specific types of integers that are particularly amenable to this type of representation? Can the identity be used to solve other types of problems in number theory as well? I would greatly appreciate any insights or references on this topic.

Comment: Dario Alpern created an app to find the representation of a positive integer as a sum of at most four squares that does not need the factorization of the given number. This might be helpful.

Comment: You might have already come across this but it might be worth looking into Lagrange's proof that every number is a sum of four squares, which heavily relies on this identity to reduce to the case of primes.

Comment: @GoodThanks: No, it does not.

Comment: Pfister's Theorem is not a theorem in number theory;  it belongs to algebra. There is a priori no reason why it should be useful in number theory.

Comment: There is a simple way to get at least one 4-square representation. Take $91$, you just take the square root so $91=9^2 +10$. Now all you need to do is expressing $10$, a small number, as a sum of squares. $10=3^2 +1^2$ so $91=9^2 +3^2 +1^2 + 0^2$. The 4-square representations are equivalent ( not proven ) meaning you can sometimes transform one into another. You want another 4-sq rep, try $91=8^2 + 27$. now $27=25 + 2= 5^2 + 1^2 + 1^2$.

Comment: If you want to get an idea on getting a 4-sq representation of an integer, you can play with this tool but avoid using large numbers. Try using number below $1000$ just to get an idea. https://www.mathcelebrity.com/foursquare.php?num=+130&pl=Show+Lagrange+Four-Square+Notation

Comment: Ah, yes my mistake, I was thinking of Euler's four square identity. Thanks for pointing that out.